# mvvmcross version 3.5.1 sqlite-pcl plugin

Tags: sqlite, plugins, mvvmcross

I cannot find this package on nuget for https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvvmCross.HotTuna.Plugin.SQLitePCL to match MvvmCross v3.5.1

There only seems to be one for v 4.0.0.0 beta.

Unfortunately I cannot use this version yet. What SQLite MvvmCross plugin should I be using to match MvvmCross 3.5.1

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no PCL plugin for pre 4.0, but you could use the old SQLite plugin: https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvvmCross.HotTuna.Plugin.Sqlite

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I'll carry on using this one. You may want to change the notes on the v3.5.1 nuget package as it references the https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvvmCross.HotTuna.Plugin.SQLitePCL package

Comment: We can't change the description of nugets that are already online. But as you can see when 4.0 hits stable it will update this one to the new Sqlite PCL plugin.